# CSS top left bottom and right scale to fit, but not in firefox?

Tags: css

I have a textbox that I want to scale to fit a div. This was easy to do in chrome:

HTML:

```
<div id="div">
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:4em;
}
#textarea {
    position:absolute;
    top:.2em;
    bottom:.2em;
    left:.2em;
    right:.2em;
    width:auto;
}
```

This works very nicely in chrome. Firefox, on the other hand, doesn't seem to like having both `left:` and `right:` or both `top:` and `bottom:`. It seems to prefer `top:` and `left:` over the other two, and won't scale the textarea to fit like in chrome. Is there a way to accomplish this in firefox, or do I have to wait for mozilla to implement this themselves?

Edit: jsfiddle, as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/Monchoman45/kKxus/

Comment: a fiddle if ye please. That is pretty standard css there, I would be pretty befuddled if it did not work in Firefox.

Comment: You need to close the TEXTAREA tag </textarea>

Comment: I would use CSS width:100%;height:100%;margin:.2em; instead

Comment: @jtheman: typo on the textarea. The ids I use are different and I have  classes for superficial things like colors, font, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T29DW/1/)

```css
#div {
    background: beige;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:4em;
    padding: .2em;
}

#textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works, but makes the element .4em taller - however, that's easy to work around.